# Wrong order of elements after GROUP BY using ST_MakeLine

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a table (well, it's CTE) containing path, as array of node IDs, and table of nodes with their geometries. I am trying to SELECT paths with their start and end nodes, and geometries, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT t.path_id, t.segment_num, t.start_node, t.end_node, ST_MakeLine(n.geom) AS geom
      FROM (SELECT path_id, segment_num, nodes[1] AS start_node, nodes[array_upper(nodes,1)] AS end_node, unnest(nodes) AS node_id
        FROM paths            
      ) t
      JOIN nodes n ON n.id = t.node_id
      GROUP BY path_id, segment_num, start_node, end_node
    ) rs
```

This seems to be working just fine when I try it on individual path samples, but when I run this on large dataset, small number of resulting geometries are bad - clearly the `ST_MakeLine` received points in wrong order. I suspect parallel aggregation resulting in wrong order, but maybe I am missing something else here?

How can I ensure correct order of points into `ST_MakeLine`?

If I am correct about the parallel aggregation, postgres [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/parallel-safety.html) are saying that `Scans of common table expressions (CTEs) are always parallel restricted`, but does that mean I have to make CTE with unnested array and mark it `AS MATERIALIZED` so it does not get optimized back into query?

Comment: `ST_MakeLine(n.geom ORDER BY ...)` you need an ordering column in `t`. `segment_num` probably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reminding me of `ST_MakeLine(geom ORDER BY something)` possibility, `ST_MakeLine` is aggregate function after all. I dont have any explicit ordering column available (order is position in `nodes` array, but one node can be present multiple times). Fortunately, `unnest` can be used in FROM clause with `WITH ORDINALITY` and therefore create an ordering column for me. Working solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT t.path_id, t.segment_num, t.start_node, t.end_node, ST_MakeLine(n.geom ORDER BY node_order) AS geom
      FROM (SELECT path_id, segment_num, nodes[1] AS start_node, nodes[array_upper(nodes,1)] AS end_node, a.elem AS node_id, a.nr AS node_order
        FROM paths, unnest(nodes) WITH ORDINALITY a(elem, nr)
      ) t
      JOIN nodes n ON n.id = t.node_id
      GROUP BY path_id, segment_num, start_node, end_node
    ) rs
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for `ST_MakeLine` to create a LineString in the right order you must explicitly state it with an `ORDER BY`. The following examples show how the order of points make a huge difference in the output:

Without ordering

```
WITH j (id,geom) AS (
 VALUES 
  (3,'SRID=4326;POINT(1 2)'::geometry),
  (1,'SRID=4326;POINT(3 4)'::geometry),
  (0,'SRID=4326;POINT(1 9)'::geometry),
  (2,'SRID=4326;POINT(8 3)'::geometry)
)
SELECT ST_MakeLine(geom) FROM j;
```

[image]

Ordering by `id`:

```
WITH j (id,geom) AS (
 VALUES 
  (3,'SRID=4326;POINT(1 2)'::geometry),
  (1,'SRID=4326;POINT(3 4)'::geometry),
  (0,'SRID=4326;POINT(1 9)'::geometry),
  (2,'SRID=4326;POINT(8 3)'::geometry)
)
SELECT ST_MakeLine(geom ORDER BY id) FROM j;
```

[image]

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b52289a75b2a0f89586687a1bf080b58)